# Fetch values in the json returned from couchbase

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, couchbase

I am getting a result set from the couchbase but it includes the bucket name in it.

I am getting an array

```
[
  {
    "test": {
      "_id": "abc"
    }
  },
  {
    "test": {
      "_id": "lmn"
    }
  }
]
```

but I want an array

```
[
  {
    "_id": "abc"
  },
  {
    "_id": "lmn"
  }
]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "but it doesn't solve my problem" --- elaborate that. Your code works just fine.

Comment: the code works fine I guess

Comment: @kukkuz I have updated my question, thanks a lot for the help. the actual code worked fine, there was an issue in my local setup

Comment: @zerkms I have updated my question, thanks a lot for the help. the actual code worked fine, there was an issue in my local setup

Comment: cool.. good to know it is solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried

```
var result = output.map(function(a) {return a.test;});
```

and it worked.

I have changed the question as there was an issue when I was running it in my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

es6 way

const result = output.map(element => element.test);